# Где находятся созданные проекты ruby on rails через vagrant на macos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vagrant

На мак поставил vagrant + virtual box.
Затем настраиваю ruby,ruby on rails, ставлю бд, ставлю все необходимые гемы.
Создаю проект, самый стандартный. Но чтобы внести в него изменения - данный проект надо найти.
Дерикторию проекта показывает home/vagrant/blog
Vagrantfile лежит в отдельной папке, в ней и был создан проект.
И я его просто не могу найти на маке:) Вопрос - может я что то не так понимаю и как мне найти проекты, которые я создаю через vagrant на macos.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вполне возможно, что они крепко заперты внутри виртуалки. Откройте её настройки в интерфейсе VirtualBox и найдите раздел общих папок. Я, правда, чаще вижу, как люди разрабатывают на маках напрямую, без виртуалок, но я не знаю в деталях ваших обстоятельств.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я думаю проблема в том, что я не до конца разобравшись в вопросе, полез туда, куда не надо. Еще мини вопрос - а по какой причине может использоваться тогда vagrant при разработке на маке? Спасибо!

Comment: Для более точного воспроизведения среды в продакшене, к примеру. Это может облегчить обнаружение и расследование некоторых классов ошибок. Но это актуально для закрытых и нераспространяемых приложений/решений (коих большинство). Для открытых/распространяемых как раз полезно тестировать на большом числе конфигураций, чтобы точнее представлять системные требования.

Comment: @D-side Спасибо!